# I created a .NET Core 7 application, for pose detection, Not able to load large files

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, large-file-upload

I am getting the following when Trying to upload a video file larger than 15 seconds for a form,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j261g.png)

The video model is as follow,

```
public class VideoUploadViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Video File")]
    public IFormFile VideoFile { get; set;}
    public string VideoFileName { get; set; }
    public string InferenceModelType { get; set; } = "Body25";
    public string OriginalVideoFilePath { get; set; }
    public string OverlayVideoFilePath { get; set; }
}
```

also,

I am using the form to upload a file,
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VideoFile, new {type = "file", @class = "form-control"})`

I tried using the following method to increase the limit,

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 512 * 1024 * 1024;
});

builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 512 * 1024 * 1024;
});
```

But still I am not able to upload large files.

Cannot figure it out in .NET 7,also there is no web.config created when I create a new project using Visual Studio.

Comment: You can create a web.config to change the limit for IIS .

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in your Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
     options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue; // if don't set default value is: 30 MB
});
  //For application running on IIS:
 builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
  {
  options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
  });
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
     x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
     x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // if don't set default value is: 128 MB
     x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```

IIS content length limit

The default request limit (maxAllowedContentLength) is 30,000,000 bytes, which is approximately 28.6MB. Customize the limit in the web.config file(you can custom create a web.config file):

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <!-- Handle requests up to 1 GB -->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi @Aroosh Ahmad , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?